# Having trouble proving an L-sentence is not logically valid

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm having trouble with an assignment in Predicate Calculus specifically related to an L-sentence. I need to prove that

$((\forall x (Px \Rightarrow Qx)) \lor(\forall x(Px \Rightarrow \lnot Qx)))$
is **not** logically valid.

I understand L-structures and in general how to determine their truth value, however I have gone over this question several times and it looks like it should be logically valid, can you show me how it's not?

Comment: How do you paraphrase this sentence in English?

Comment: (For all x, if Px then Qx) or (For all x, if Px then not Qx)

Comment: Right. Is it possible for some $a$ to satisfy $\neg(Pa \Rightarrow Qa)$ and for some different $b$ to satisfy $\neg(Pb \Rightarrow \neg Qb)$?

Comment: Sure, if a made Pa True and Qa False, and then b made Pb True and Qb True.
Like if Px meant "x is positive" and Qx meant "x is greater than 5" and then we could chose a = 3 and b = 6

Comment: Correct. Therefore $(\exists x \neg(Px \Rightarrow Qx)) \wedge (\exists x \neg(Px \Rightarrow \neg Qx))$ is satisfiable.

Comment: Oh my gosh, for some reason I thought the x needed to be the same across the whole equation! So because the whole equation isn't in the scope of the initial $\forall x$ I can have different values, right?

Comment: What is an 'L-sentence'?

Comment: A sentence of (first-order) language $L$, I presume.

Comment: Yes, the values of $x$ that contradict the two parts may be different.  You could rewrite the second part as $\forall y(Py \Rightarrow \neg Qy)$ without changing its meaning.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question was resolved in the comments. Just adding this note so the question stops showing in lists of unanswered questions.